# Auto Unboxing in java using ListIterator

Tags: java, list, iterator

Auto-unboxing seems to not work when using ListIterator.
The code below throws a compile-time error stating **"incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to int"**

```
import java.util.*;
class Input_Array
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String x = "36 42 74 98 41 85";
        String y[]  = x.split(" ");
        int p[] = new int [6];
        ArrayList<Integer> lst  = new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0;
        for(String v : y)
        {
            lst.add(Integer.valueOf(v));
        }
        ListIterator X = lst.listIterator(lst.size());
        while(X.hasPrevious())
        {
            int n=X.previous();
            System.out.print(n+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

.
Replacing line 18 with

```
int n=(int)X.previous();
```

seems to work pretty good. Isn't auto unboxing(automatic conversion of Object type to their primitive) supported by Listiterators?

Comment: Boxing conversions have nothing to do with `Object`.  They have to do with the defined wrapper classes, such as `Integer` and `Boolean` and `Long`, etc.

Comment: It is perhaps unclear why the given dupe target is relevant.  The problem is that `ListIterator` is a generic type, and you are using it raw (without a type parameter).

Comment: @JohnBollinger thank You. That explains the solution to the question.